# Does Tibco Hawk comes with Tibco tra 5.7.1?

Tags: tibco

I have read the documentation given below

https://docs.tibco.com/pub/runtime_agent/5.7.2_november_2011/doc/pdf/tib_tra_installation.pdf

I came to know that Tibco Hawk Agent comes with tra.

Is it something like Tibco Hawk Agent earlier was not coming with tra and and after a certain tra 5.x release it started coming with tra ?

Actually I am trying to deploy my projects
and I got from the link

https://docs.tibco.com/pub/activematrix_businessworks/5.10.0_june_2012/doc/html/tib_bw_administration/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm#context=tib_bw_administration&file=admin.5.03.htm

that to run Tibco Administrator Server we need Tibco Hawk agent service.

so I want to know that after installing the below Tibco products , will i able to deploy my projects ?

```
1) Tibco Tra.
2) Tibco BW
3) Tibco EMS.
4) Tibco Administration.
```

and do i need any other products than the above list to deploy my projects ear.

Please Help me out ?

Comment: This is a reworked variant of your earlier question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19858043/what-is-use-of-tibco-hawk-and-rendezvous  Delete one or the other, SO is strongly against multiple posting of the same question.

Comment: okk i have deleted the question, but someone please answer this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*do i need any other products than the above list to deploy my projects ear*
This much is sufficient,even Tibco BW is not required to deploy.Tibco BW is used to create application not for deploying.Even Tibco Bw is not required to build EAR also.Please go for buildear utility for this purpose.
Before deploying please make sure that Tibco HAWK is running.To know the status of Tibco HAWK go to run->type services.msc
Search for tibco HAWK and if it is not running then start it
Please see these links for more info and examples on buildear and appmanage
http://architektdomain.com/architekt/index.php?topic=72.0;wap2
http://tibcowithbts.wordpress.com/2012/05/10/steps-to-build-an-ear-file-testapp-and-deploy-it-from-command-promptscripted-deployment/

Answer (score 2):

The exact same question has already been asked and answered here: https://www.tibcommunity.com/message/90854

Comment: sorry for the mistake.I know this can be done using buildear but I was in hurry other other answers.I have changed the answer.Fell free to write a comment if you find something in my answers.

Answer (score 0):

It is best that you install each component separately and you configure them in the .TRA files. To answer your question TIBCO Hawk requires a communication channel: EMS, RV, FTL. 
I suggest you make a diagram of your goal and which communication method you are going to use to monitor your administrator environment then you decide to configure Hawk. 
Based on those version used I have some posts on tibcommunity on TIBCO Hawk Display and TIBCO HAwk Agent. 
[tibcommunity](https://community.tibco.com/questions/i-am-new-tibco-and-i-have-been-assigned-work-quot#node-715301)